# Minimum no of table generation from E-R mapping

Tags: database

[image]

what will be minimum no of table will be mapped from this entity relationship model.

here M1 IS PRIMARY KEY.
P1 IS PRIMARY KEY,
N1 IS DESCRIMINATOR OF WEAK ENTITY SET E3. AND 
R1 IS A RELATION SHIP (MANY TO ONE)(FROM E1 TO E2) 
R2 IS A RELATION SHIP (MANY TO ONE )(FROM E3 TO E2)
E1 HAS TOTAL PARTICIPATION IN R1
AND E3 HAS ALSO TOTAL PARTICIPATION.

WHAT WILL BE MINIMUM NO OF TABLE (RELATION SCHEMA ) WILL BE ?

Comment: what do you think about it ? i think you don't like to do homework...that's why question looks like to you homework question....isn't it....

Comment: No - I ask the question because there is a specific homework tag for homework questions. I think this is homework because both the nature of the questions and the format of the supplied data are typical of what would be expected from an academic exercise, rather than what would be expected from a real-world problem. (If I simply didn't want to do it, I wouldn't have bothered posting a question.)

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge it should be decompose into 2 tables.

1. E1R1(M1, M2, M3, P1) Primary key P1
2. E3R2(P1, N1, N2) Primary Key P1N1

Since both relations have been decomposed and since nothing left so only these 2 are in the solution.

First we will combine table 1, in which entity E1 and E2 will be coupled and its primary key will be P1.(no matter there exist total participation since it only considered when present with one to one relationship).

Now since E3 is weak so Primary key of E1R1 and E3 is coupled and Primary key of resultant will be P1N1 combined.

Since you asked for minimum no of tables thats why it is 2, else maximum no of table will be 3.